# make absolute elements take 100% width of the browser window and move the content below

Tags: html, css

html

```
<div id="navBar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="">z</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">WORKS</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ARTICLES</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">u</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Advertise</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sources</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">s</li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#navBar{
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #0088FF;
}
#navBar ul{
    float: right;
}
#navBar ul li{
    float: left;
    padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
}
#navBar ul li a{

}


/*-------Media Queries---------*/    
    @media only screen
            and (max-width : 500px) {
            #navBar ul li ul{
                display: none;
            }
            #navBar ul li{
                position: relative;
            }
            #navBar ul li:hover > ul{
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
            }
    }
```

The problem is, when the width is below `500px` I want to display the elements something like below:
[image]

I need to display those elements relative to the content of the page which will move the content below down, and as well make elements take the full width of the page, something like `width: 100%`. Kinda stuck there and need your help. Thanks

[new jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LkMgx/1/)

Comment: Please move this to jsfiddle so we can see it in action/tweak it.

Comment: @BotskoNet I've included a fiddle of what I have achieved so far.

Comment: I'm really not clear on what the issue is and the goal is. You're referring to widths but I don't know which elements you're talking about. Give me an idea of what you have now, versus what you want, and what you've tried.

Comment: Absolute positioning takes a element out of the flow, so it _can not_ push the following content down.

Comment: @BotskoNet, as you can see in the `fiddle` when you hover over `z` or `u`, elements under`(WORKS, ARTICLES, ABOUT)` are displayed. That is not where I want them to be displayed. I want those elements to be displayed like the screenshot above when hovered over `z` or `u`. Just to be clear, when you hover `z`, `WORKS, ARTICLES, ABOUT` will be displayed and when you hover over `u` the other set of elements will be displayed. I'm not sure what styles should I be using next to display the elements similar to the screenshot.

Comment: Nothing happens for me on mouse hover in the fiddle, on any of the anchors?

Comment: @BotskoNet, sorry the fiddle was larger than 500px. Please check it out now.

Comment: If you want the submenus to occupy the same region, you'll need to use `position: absolute`. Looks like the sub items need to be floated or inline-block so they display horizontally

Comment: @BotskoNet, I am using `position:absolute`.

Comment: I meant you'd need to position them in the exact same place. Right now they're absolute, but each in a relative parent. This gives you an idea of how to position the elements over each other http://jsfiddle.net/e6Y7N/

Comment: @BotskoNet I can actually make them display floated left by applying the width to the parent element. But when I apply `width: 100%` it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you trying make the entire submenu `width: 100%`? If so you need the `li`s inside to automatically fit

Comment: I *think* I get what you want with the widths... it's tricky to gets the widths of the elements to always line up when using positioning like this, but does this work for: http://jsfiddle.net/e6Y7N/2/